# RSA Decryption Printing NULL

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bufferedreader, printwriter

I believe I am doing this right. How I see decrypting a file with RSA:

1. Read in each line of the file as a `String`
2. Set `cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)`
3. Convert String to `char[]` using `Hex.decodeHex(String.toCharArray())`
4. Lastly do `cipher.doFinal(x)`

Does this sound right? I'm doing this but it is not working and `DecryptedFile.txt` is just 2 lines of "null".

I'm able to encrypt using pretty much the same exact process but with `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)` obviously.

Here's my code

```
try {
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(cryptoFile));

        int k = 0;

        fileContents.add(inStream.readLine());

        while(fileContents.get(k) != null) {
            k++;
            fileContents.add(inStream.readLine());
        }

        inStream.close();

        try {

            PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

            int j = 0;

            while(fileContents.get(j) != null) {

                String text = fileContents.get(j);

                try {                        
                    x = Hex.decodeHex(text.toCharArray());
                    y = cipher.doFinal(x);
                } catch (DecoderException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Crypto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                try (PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(
                        new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("DecryptedFile.txt", true)))) {
                    file.println(y);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("IOERROR: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
                }

                j++;
            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Crypto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("IOERROR: File NOT Found: " + cryptoFile + "\n");
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        System.err.println("IOERROR: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
    } finally {
        messagePane.setText(messagePane.getText() + "\n\n"
                + cryptoFile + "is done being decrypted.");
        messagePane.setText(messagePane.getText() + "\n"
                + "Decrypted file saved to \'DecryptedFile.txt\'.");

        cryptoFile = "";
        pathTextField.setText(cryptoFile);
        encryptButton.setEnabled(false);
        decryptButton.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

Comment: RSA is actually a slow algorithm - usually you wouldn't use it to encrypt a file, instead you'd encrypt a file with AES and then you'd encrypt the AES key using RSA.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot I have to write a program of my choice for a final project in my class and we were told we had to use RSA within it.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case no worries - just don't do this in production code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the cipher on a character array derived from a String derived from FileContents - this is probably screwing up its encoding.  Instead, read a byte array from the file and use this as input to the cipher.

It's a good idea to pad the input if necessary - use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")`

Always specify the character encoding (e.g. `str.getBytes("UTF-8")`) when converting a string to bytes and vice versa - different JVMs use different default character encodings.

Comment: would this change if i told you that i encrypted the file line by line and then saved?

Comment: It depends on how you saved the data.  If you took a string, converted it to byte[], encrypted it, and saved it to a file, then you'll need to read in precisely that same byte[] as input for the decryption function.  I'm not sure what the best way is to do this; you'll probably need to change your output function in order to make it easier to read the data back in, e.g. convert a string to a byte[], encrypt it, save its length, then save the byte array, so that your file would be e.g. 120[array of 120 bytes]; now you can read in 120, then read in the next 120 bytes, then decrypt them.

Comment: Best to make that length field fixed-size, probably two bytes ought to do it, so it would be [0][120][120 bytes of data].  Don't forget that bytes are signed in Java, so [0][128][128 bytes of data] will be read in as -127 bytes of data if you're not careful.

Comment: I'm saving each line as a seperate byte array to the text file with the length of the byte array before the array. For example the first line is "128 [B@30479402" and the second is "128 [B@2b462811".

Comment: In that case it shouldn't be a problem to read in the data to byte arrays.  Probably the easiest way to do this is to read in the entire thing to a byte array via ByteArrayInputStream(FileInputStream), then parse out the resulting byte array to sub-arrays that you can decrypt.

Comment: how would you do the ByteArrayInputStream(FileInputStream) because when i try that it tells me that is an invalid constructor.

Comment: My bad, I'm thinking of a different library.  Are you using Java7?  In that case import `import java.nio.file.Files; import java.nio.file.Paths; import java.nio.file.Path;` and then use `byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(/* file path */));`

Comment: should i move this over to chat? anyways, let me know if i'm understanding this correctly: doing the Files.readAllBytes reads all of the bytes in the text file into one long byte array? I'm just not understanding how to get it from that into each part needing to be decrypted.

Comment: Given byte[] bytes that contains the contents of the file, read the first byte into an int (to prevent a byte greater than 127 from being read as a negative value), int size = bytes[0]; Now allocate byte[] data = new byte[size]; for(int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++) { data[i] = bytes[i]; } Now repeat with size = bytes[1 + size] and so on

Comment: i actually figured it all out. what i did was rather than saving the byte arrays to the text file, i saved a hex representation of the byte to the text file then did just the reverse when opening. was really simple and worked flawlessly. thanks for the help and pushing me in the right direction!